# Why is sklearn's paired_distances a lot slower than pairwise_distances even when calculating the same data? How can we improve paired_distances?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've been running this simple code to calculate the distance matrix of X:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import paired_distances
import time

n = 10000
X = np.random.RandomState(0).rand(n, 5)

t0 = time.time()
pairwise_distances(X, X)
print(time.time() - t0)

X_tile = np.tile(X, (n, 1))
X_repeat = np.repeat(X, n, axis=0)

t1 = time.time()
paired_distances(X_tile, X_repeat)
print(time.time() - t1)
```

This returns (on my laptop, a 2014 MacBook Pro):

```
7.2921271324157715
448.4537389278412
```

The two functions are effectively returning the same values. What makes `paired_distances` 60x slower than `pairwise_distances`? And if, say, we *need* to use `paired_distances` -- perhaps because we're looking for the distances between points in a matrix to different (possibly random) sets of neighbors (say, in a matrix `X`, I need distances from `X[0]` to `X[1], X[2]`, whereas for `X[1]`, I need distances to `X[2], X[3]` etc...) how can we improve its performance?

Comment: I get times of `1.44` and `3.85` - a factor of ~2 is consistent with the fact that `pairwise_distances` should do about half the computation as `paired_distances` (because distance is symmetric).  Don't know what's going on for you though...

Comment: Due to memory restrictions I used 10 times less data, but also got results matching with @bogovicj results of 0.02439403533935547 and 0.04340338706970215, so also with a factor of around 2.